# How can I use query() instead of execute()?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here is my current code:

```
$stm = $db_connection->prepare("SELECT name FROM tag WHERE category = 1");
$stm->execute();
$results = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $results[0]['name']; //=> tgname
die;
```

I works as well. But as you see, no need to use `prepare()` and `execute()` in this case, because I don't want to escape anything. I mean, in query above, I don't have any parameter to pass it. So I want to use `query()` instead.

Here is my new code:

```
$result = $db_connection->query("SELECT * FROM tag WHERE cat = 1");
var_dump($results);
die;
```

But the result is an *object*. And when I print `$result->name`, it prints nothing. Anyway, how can I use `query()` instead of `execute()` ?

Comment: Hint: Step one is, as always, [read the manual entry on `query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php).

Comment: @tadman So I cannot use `query()` and get a result? `query()` doesn't return result at all ?

Comment: You probably have to iterate over the result since it will contain zero or more rows.

Comment: query returns [the same statement as prepare](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#query). thus for getting results [**exactly same methods** have to be used](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#foreach).

Comment: `$result = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM tag  WHERE cat = 1")->fetchAll();` - yes, it's as easy as that, like others said - it's in the manual.